# ADODB Connection String for .csv

Tags: excel, vba, connection-string, adodb

I want to process .csv files with ADODB in Excel VBA. I tried a few strings found on web, but none of them seems to work. I'm getting file path using:

```
strVFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV (*.csv), *.csv")
```

And then I pass `strVFile` as a parameter to the sub `objReport.Load strVFile`. The header of the sub is: `Public Sub Load(ByVal strFilename As String)`.

Then I try to make ADODB connection using string:

```
pconConnection.ConnectionString = _
            "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFilename & _
            ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(;)"";Persist Security Info=False"
    pconConnection.Open
```

When I run the macro and choose CSV file, there's error occuring saying that "given path is not a valid path". What am I doing wrong?

**Edit (Code)**,

Module mdlReport

```
Public Sub Report()
    Dim objReport As clsReport


    MsgBox "Please select .csv file", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
    strVFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV (*.csv), *.csv")

    If strVFile <> False Then
        Set objReport = New clsReport

        objReport.Load strVFile

    End If
End Sub
```

Class clsReport

```
Private pconConnection As ADODB.Connection
Private prstRecordset As ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
  Set pconConnection = New ADODB.Connection
  pconConnection.ConnectionTimeout = 40
End Sub

Public Sub Load(ByVal strFilename As String)

    pconConnection.ConnectionString = _
            "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFilename & _
            ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(;)"";Persist Security Info=False"
    pconConnection.Open

End Sub
```

Comment: could you post your full code so that we could test it?

Comment: Temporarily use `Debug.Print` or `MsgBox` to show the value of `strFilename` immediately before you use it in the connection string. Check that it shows a full path to the required file. Also, `Delimited(;)` should be `Delimited(,)` for a CSV I would think

Comment: I've added some code, it's just a few lines, but it should show my problem. I've tried to look at the path and it seems to be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. For text files (as stated by Remou) `Data Source` is just the folder path, without file name. In addition instead of using:

```
C:\dir\dir2\
```

I had to use

```
C:\\dir\\dir2\\
```

To get file name from full path:

```
strFilename = Dir(strFilepath)
```

To get the path only, without a file name:

```
strFilepath = Left$(strFilepath, InStrRev(strFilepath, "\"))
```

To change path format from '\' to '\\' I just used:

```
strFilepath = Replace(strFilepath, "\", "\\")
```

The problem is solved, thanks for interest.

Answer (score 13):

For a text file, `Data Source` is the folder, not the file. The file is the table (SELECT * FROM   ..). See http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile

Answer (score 3):

Here is an update using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 as provider.

Make sure the reference library "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library" is added to VBAproject first.

```
Sub testrunSQLQueryForCSV()
    Dim arrayTest
    arrayTest = runSQLQueryForCSV("C:\xxx\yyyy\", "SELECT * FROM mycsvfile.csv")

    'NOTE: for CSV the Data Source reference is to the directory and the csv file is similar
    'to one "worksheet" in an excel file and is simply referenced in the SQL statement
End Sub


Public Function runSQLQueryForCSV(fileDirPath As String, SQLStatement As String)

    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim RecSet As New ADODB.Recordset

    With Conn
       .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0"  'Can use many providers, but this is the latest and it works with csv files also
       .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & fileDirPath & ";Extended Properties='text'"
    End With

    Conn.Open

    RecSet.Open SQLStatement, Conn
    runSQLQueryForCSV = RecSet.GetRows()

    Conn.Close
    Set RecSet = Nothing
    Set Conn = Nothing
End Function
```