# Excel text connection string file path invalid

Tags: c#, excel, connection-string

I'm attempting to write a connection string for a `.txt` file with C#.

I keep getting the error saying that my file path is invalid.

```
string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Test.txt;Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited""";
```

The file path shouldn't be wrong. So, I'm thinking it's some other problem. Perhaps I'm missing something with the file path though.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Try adding double-quotes around the path, as in `"C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Test.txt"` (and remove the wrong `Extended Properties=""text` - the `text` doesn't belong there).

Comment: I need to add multiple sets of double quotes to keep the path with the string. Also, should I replace "text" with anything in the Extend Propteries? Or leave it exactly blank?

Comment: The word `text` does not belong there at all. It should either be inside the `""` or removed entirely. [ConnectionStrings](http://connectionstrings.com) is a site you should bookmark if you're going to do much with ADO.

Comment: This is the string I've been referencing from the connectionstrings site. Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\txtFilesFolder\;
Extended Properties="text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Fixed"; I've been using it, but I must be missing something still. This string has "text" in it, it also does not have double quotes around the file path like you suggested. Am I referencing the wrong string from the website? I'm looking in their text file section under microsoft oledb jet delimited column string

Comment: That new string has double quotes with the `"text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Fixed"` **inside** the quotes; your original one had `""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Fixed`, with the text **following** (after) the  quotes. Can't you see the difference? If not, copy and paste each of them into a text editor, each on it's own line, and compare them character by character. The new one should be correct.

Comment: Double double quotes are just a way to 'escape' the single double quote in C# @literal. I think the connection is fine - you just need to drop the file name and leave only the folder path.

Answer (score 2):

For text files the data source is a directory not an individual file see:
[ADODB Connection String for .csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315957/adodb-connection-string-for-csv)

So the connection string should be

```
string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; 
Data Source=C:\Users\Josh\Documents\;Extended Properties=""text;
HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited""";
```

Then you would do

`SELECT * FROM Test.txt`

To get at the data