# VBA Replace last field in ALL rows within csv around double quotes?

Tags: vba, csv, text

```
On Error Resume Next


Set FileSysObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Const ForReading = 1                ' Declare constant for reading for more clarity
Dim cntFile, strCSVFullFile, strCSVFile, strDIR, cntBadLines, cntAllLines, strArchiveDir, strSafeTime,strSafeDate  

' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Specify CSV file name from the input argument
strCSVFile =  Wscript.Arguments(1)          ' Transactions
strDIR =  Wscript.Arguments(2)  & "\"       ' C:\Temp

strArchiveDir = Wscript.Arguments(3) & "\"

strSafeTime = Right("0" & Hour(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Minute(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Second(Now), 2)
strSafeDate = Year(Date) & Month(Date) &  day(Date)

set folder = FileSysObj.getFolder(strDIR)
cntFile = 0
cntBadLines = 0
cntAllLines = 0

for each file in folder.Files

    ' check if the file is there and echo it.
    if InStr(1,file.name,strCSVFile,1) <> 0 then 
          strCSVFullFile = file.name
        cntFile = cntFile + 1
    end if

  next

if cntFile > 1 or cntFile = 0 then
    ' error and end
    Wscript.Echo "Error - only 1 file required for this process. There are " & cntFile & " file(s) in the directory"
    WScript.Quit
end if

wscript.echo "Checking the file " & strCSVFullFile & " in " & strDIR



NoOfCols = Wscript.Arguments(0)         ' usually 8

strTemp = "temp.csv"
strmissing = "missingdata.csv"
Set objOutFile = FileSysObj.CreateTextFile(strDIR  & strTemp,True)
Set objOutFileM = FileSysObj.CreateTextFile(strDIR  & strmissing,True)


Set inputFile = FileSysObj.OpenTextFile(strDIR  & strCSVFullFile, ForReading, True) 
' Set inputFile as file to be read from

Dim row, column, outline  
Dim fields '(7) '8 fields per line  
inputFile.ReadAll 'read to end of file  
outline  = ""

ReDim MyArray(inputFile.Line-2,NoOfCols)    'current line, minus one for header, and minus one for starting at zero  
inputFile.close                     'close file so that MyArray can be filled with data starting at the top


Set inputFile = FileSysObj.OpenTextFile(strDIR  & strCSVFullFile, ForReading, True) 'back at top  
strheadLine = inputFile.ReadLine                'skip header , but keep it for the output file

objOutFile.Write(strheadLine & vbCrLf)
anyBadlines = False
badlineflag = False


Do Until inputFile.AtEndOfStream  
    fullLine = inputFile.Readline
    fields = Split(fullLine,",")            'store line in temp array  

    For column = 0 To NoOfCols-1            'iterate through the fields of the temp array  
        myArray(row,column) = fields(column)        'store each field in the 2D array with the given coordinates  
    'Wscript.Echo myArray(row,column)

    if myArray(row,0) = " " or myArray(row,1) = " " then
        badlineflag = True
        'missline = myArray(row,0) & ", " & myArray(row,1) & ", " & myArray(row,2) & ", " & myArray(row,3) & ", " & myArray(row,4) & ", " & myArray(row,5) & ", " & myArray(row,6) & ", " & myArray(row,7)
        'Wscript.Echo missline 
        'Exit For
    end if

    if column = NoOfCols-1 then
        outline = outline  & myArray(row,column) & vbCrLf
    else
        outline = outline  & myArray(row,column) & ","
                'csvFile = Regex.Replace(csvFile, "(,\s*?"".*?)(,)(\s+.*?""\s*?,)", "$1$3") 'TEST

    end if
    Next
    cntAllLines = cntAllLines + 1
    ' Wscript.Echo outline
    if badlineflag = False then
        objOutFile.Write(fullLine & vbCrLf)
    else
        ' write it somewhere else, drop a header in the first time
        if anyBadlines = False Then
            objOutFileM.Write(strheadLine & vbCrLf)
        End if
        objOutFileM.Write(outline)
        cntBadLines = cntBadLines  + 1
        badlineflag = False
        anyBadlines = True
    end if
    outline  = ""

    row = row + 1  'next line 
Loop
objOutFile.Close
objOutFileM.Close

inputFile.close

Wscript.Echo "Total lines in the transaction file = " & cntAllLines 
Wscript.Echo "Total bad lines in the file = " & cntBadLines
```

The below line is able to work as it contains 7 commas (8 columns).

```
URXW_99,BYQ0JC6,2603834418,2017-10-30,Test,4.962644,2278.0000,ABC
```

The below line will throw an error as a result of more commas than 7 in the script.

```
URXW_99,BYQ0JC6,2603834418,2017-10-30,Test,4.962644,2278.0000,Redburn, Europe. Limited
```

If greater than 7 commas in the CSV file line, the aim is to wrap it all greater than 7 into one field.
E.g. how do you replace Redburn, Europe. Limited string with double quotes as it is one name.

For example, in a text file it would appear like below:

```
URXW_99,BYQ0JC6,2603834418,2017-10-30,Test,4.962644,2278.0000,"Redburn, Europe. Limited"
```

**Is there a way to write a VB or VBA script to do the above and save it as a .csv file (which is opened via notepad to check the double quotes)?**

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Public Sub ConvertFile()
Dim lngRowNumber As Long
Dim strLineFromFile As String
Dim strSourceFile As String
Dim strDestinationFile As String
strSourceFile = "U:\Book3.csv"
strDestinationFile = "U:\Book4.csv"
Open strSourceFile For Input As #1
Open strDestinationFile For Output As #2
lngRowNumber = 0
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, strLineFromFile
    strLineFromFile = Right(Replace(strLineFromFile, ",", " ", 1), 1000)
    Write #2, strLineFromFile
    strLineFromFile = vbNullString
Loop
Close #1
Close #2
End Sub
```

Comment: What does the Above code do ?

Comment: The descriptions for the VB.NET and VBA tags specifically state that they are different languages and those tags are not to be used for the other language.  Please don't spam tags.

Comment: the above code just adds blank spaces for each comma in a text file or csv file with rows of data like        URXW_99,BYQ0JC6,2603834418,2017-10-30,Test,4.962644,2278.0000,ABC                                                                                                                                                                                 I want to see if I can wrap double quotes around any string  that exists after the 7th comma? Is this possible?

Comment: the above code just adds blank spaces for each comma in a text file or csv file with rows of data like URXW_99,BYQ0JC6,2603834418,2017-10-30,Test,4.962644,2278.0000,ABC.                                                              I want to see if I can wrap double quotes around any string that exists after the 7th comma and is a string that has a comma within it (E.g. convert A,B,C to "A,B,C")? Is this possible? – jv123 10 mins ago

Comment: @jv123 Use the ADODB driver for text files. It can read CSV files, it supports configurable delimiter characters and understands double quotes. Random question on that topic to get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315957/adodb-connection-string-for-csv - search from there.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you use MS Access (due to `Option Compare Text` line), so there is better built-in instruments for this task.
Use `DoCmd.TransferText` for it.

1st step is to create output specification via:
[image]

[image]
Here you can setup delimiters, even that differs from `"`, and handle other options.

After that you can use your set-up specification via following command

```vb
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "TblCustomers_export_spec", "TblCustomers", "C:\test\1.txt", True
```

In this case all characters escaping would be done through built-in instruments. It seems to be more easier to correct this code further.

As mentioned, there is VBScript workaround. For given input data, following function will do desired actions for given string:

```vb
Option Explicit

Function funAddLastQuotes( _
                        strInput _
                        )

    Dim arrInput
    arrInput = Split(strInput, ",")
    Dim intArrSize 
    intArrSize = UBound(arrInput)

    Dim intCurrentElement 
    Dim strOutput 
    Dim intPreLastElement
    intPreLastElement = 6
    For intCurrentElement = 1 To intPreLastElement
        strOutput = strOutput & "," & arrInput(intCurrentElement)
    Next

    Dim strOutputLastField

    For intCurrentElement = intPreLastElement + 1 To intArrSize
        strOutputLastField = strOutputLastField & "," & arrInput(intCurrentElement)
    Next
    strOutputLastField = Right(strOutputLastField, Len(strOutputLastField) - 1)
    strOutput = Right(strOutput, Len(strOutput) - 1)
    strOutput = strOutput & "," & """" & strOutputLastField & """"
    funAddLastQuotes = strOutput
End Function

MsgBox funAddLastQuotes("RXW_99,BYQ0JC6,2603834418,2017-10-30,Test,4.962644,2278.0000,Redburn, Europe,,, Limited")
```

Comment: No, not in access. Via a vb script, is there a way to wrap the last string on a row within a text file with double quotes?

Comment: It would not be easy to my mind, because it will can cause many undesired conclusions. This should be done at the beginning, at string formatting, could you provide code, that provides you string? `RXW_99,BYQ0JC6,2603834418,2017-10-30,Test,4.962644,2278.0000,Redburn, Europe. Limited` Or it is the side application that provides such data? In this case it is better to call support, and ask them for options, that switchs on the characters escaping option. And answer is yes, it is possible to wrap it, via counting commas and so on.

Comment: @jv123, see updated answer with VBScript code, that for given string for you template, escapes 7th element with `"`

Comment: Is there a way to do it for all strings in a text file ('escapes 7th element with  ") ? Is there a way to wrap the last string on ALL rows within a text file with double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, here is working VBScript solution.

```vb
Option Explicit
Const ColumnsBeforeCommadColumn = 6
Function funAddLastQuotes( _
                        strInput _
                        )
    Dim arrInput
    arrInput = Split(strInput, ",")
    Dim intArrSize 
    intArrSize = UBound(arrInput)

    Dim intCurrentElement 
    Dim strOutput 
    Dim intPreLastElement
    intPreLastElement = ColumnsBeforeCommadColumn
    For intCurrentElement = 1 To intPreLastElement
        strOutput = strOutput & "," & arrInput(intCurrentElement)
    Next

    Dim strOutputLastField
    If (intPreLastElement + 1) < intArrSize _
    Then
        For intCurrentElement = intPreLastElement + 1 To intArrSize
            strOutputLastField = strOutputLastField & "," & arrInput(intCurrentElement)
        Next
    Else
        strOutputLastField = strOutputLastField & "," & arrInput(intArrSize)
    End If
    strOutputLastField = Right(strOutputLastField, Len(strOutputLastField) - 1)
    strOutput = Right(strOutput, Len(strOutput) - 1)
    strOutput = strOutput & "," & """" & strOutputLastField & """"
    funAddLastQuotes = strOutput
End Function
Public Sub ConvertFile( _
                        strSourceFile _
                        )
    Dim objFS
    Dim strFile
    Dim strTemp
    Dim ts
    Dim objOutFile
    Dim objFile
    Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim strLine
    Dim strOutput
    Dim strRow
    strFile = strSourceFile
    strTemp = strSourceFile & ".tmp"
    Set objFile = objFS.GetFile(strFile)
    Set objOutFile = objFS.CreateTextFile(strTemp,True)
    Set ts = objFile.OpenAsTextStream(1,-2)
    Do Until ts.AtEndOfStream
        strLine = ts.ReadLine
        objOutFile.WriteLine funAddLastQuotes(strLine)      
    Loop
    objOutFile.Close
    ts.Close
    objFS.DeleteFile(strFile)
    objFS.MoveFile strTemp,strFile 
End Sub
ConvertFile "C:\!accsoft\_in.csv"
```

- You should change following part: `ConvertFile "C:\!accsoft\_in.csv` as path to your file.
- And `ColumnsBeforeCommadColumn = 6` is the setting, at which column the chaos with commas begins