# changing a data source for an excel oledb connection

Tags: excel, vba, oledb

I have an excel workbook, with 10 sheets. Each sheet contains an oledb connection pointing to a .csv file.
Each connection was originally created to point to a specific .csv file.

I want to use VB to change the name of the .csv file.
When I attempted to retrieve the name of the source file using:

```
?ActiveWorkbook.Connections(8).OLEDBConnection.SourceDataFile
```

nothing is returned. only whitespace.

then I noticed, that using:

```
?ActiveWorkbook.Connections(8).OLEDBConnection.connection
```

returns this:

```
OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=PAIDOFF_L2500;Extended Properties=""
```

I'm stumped... if the source is $Workbook$, how do change the location of the datafile.

Comment: Answer to your question is probably here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315957/adodb-connection-string-for-csv) last solution :).

Comment: That solution was for ADOBD connections. My issue is with OLEDB connections, -so none of the information was useful. Thanks anyway

Comment: There might be something relevant here https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/change-data-source-of-oledbconnection.988066/